# RGB to Red-White-Blue gradient

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geotiff-tiff, rgb

I have tiff RGB data that I want to transform in vector attribute color gradiente, in which Red means 0, white is 0.5 and Blue is 1:

[image]

For a blue-green-red gradient I used the formula 255*R+G-255*B and after that normalize, and it works.

I've tried different formulae for the red-white-blue gradiente from RGB but they are not matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the gradient into an image editor (eg gimp) and split into RGB single-band layers (actually maybe QGIS can do this...). You'll see how each colour band changes individually, and creating a simple function to map those values to (0,1) along the gradient might not be trivial, depending on the accuracy you want.

Here's the red, green and blue components, rotated 90 degrees clockwise from the gradient:

[image]

Notice that each channel goes up from either black or gray to white and then down, so for any (r,g,b) triple in that palette you get two locations on each channel. The slope might not even be linear or symmetric, and is different for the channels, which really complicates things.

I don't think a simple formula can capture this accurately, if you really want to reverse-engineer the data values from a paletted image you might have to write some code that takes (r,g,b) triples and finds the value in the palette that minimises the colour difference...

Another possible approach: note that for any green value your point is in one of two places - and if red is higher than blue then the point is on the left side of the image, if blue is higher then the right half. So a conditional expression based on the green value with an adjustment if R > B might get you some of the way, but I still think looking at it that non-linearities are going to mess you up a bit. The green component here isn't symmetric (there's more low values (dark) on the left than the right...

Comment: Thank you for your response, it helps me to get to the point.

Indeed I have raster layer with (r,g,b) band at each pixel and QGIS hexagon grid overlayed.
Applying zonal statistics I can get (r,g,b) mean value at each hexagon.

After that, using field calculator and inspired by your response, I applied the formula:
if(_Gmean<_Rmean,_Gmean-_Rmean,_Bmean-_Gmean)

While not exact, It seem pretty accurate. 
Thank you.